# C# : Cast from List<T> to MyCollection<T> : IList<T>

Tags: c#, types, casting, automapper

I have a collection object which utilises a List internally and implements IList<T

```
public class ModelCollection<T> : IModelCollection<T>
    where T : IModel
{  ... }

public interface IModelCollection<T> : IList, IList<T>
{  ... }
```

I also have model objects which may contains the collection ...

```
public class Article : Model, IArticle
{ 
    public IModelCollection<IArticleVariant> Variants { get; set; }
}

public interface IArticle : IModel
{
    IModelCollection<IArticleVariant> Variants { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using automapper to translate data from EF objects into the model classes, however I'm struggling to cast from List to IModelCollection as obviously List doesn't know this newly created type. I also have no access to the innerworkings of Automapper so extensibility doesn't appear to be an option. The error message is as follows ...

```
Unable to cast object of type 

'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IArticle]' to type 'IModelCollection`1[IArticle]'.
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Tim

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Open-Generics.html

Comment: You don't appear to be able to use generics on this as its a collection and there is little point in using the .ConvertUsing as the collection will contain unmapped raw EF models which can't then be mapped in the conversion function.

Comment: Of course you can. You just have to write the code.